# Handle image binary file returned from the server

Tags: javascript, html, nginx

The server is sending me an image through an API call. I'm unsure how to convert it to base64 and show as image src. The FileReader's readAsDataURI says it's not type of blob. However, the browser's network panel does preview the image correctly. The server is not sending a 'Content-Type' header with the response, can this be the issue? [screenshot of the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYxyk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the chrome dev tool shows the image correctly then it is a valid blob file.
You just need to set the response type in your request and also You can use the [createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to generate the image

Here is a sample snippet

```
    function response(e) {
        var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        console.log(this.response);
        var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(this.response);
        document.querySelector("#image").src = imageUrl;
        }
    function GetImageBlob(){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "https://secret/upload/IMG_1_201810220930_1.jpg");
        //Set Header if is required by the api
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1NDAyMTg5MDYsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly9yc3YtZGV2LmJsb3RvY29sLnRlY2gvYWRtaW4iLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwOi8vcnN2LWRldi5ibG90b2NvbC50ZWNoL2FkbWluIn0.YTHKhrl05PWDWCkHB1Nw7yW5166NiyGG3kZ_7SWfT1I");
        xhr.responseType = "blob";
        xhr.onload = response;
        xhr.send();
    }
    GetImageBlob();
```